# jQuery addEventListener not supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simple page with HTML5 video and trying to prevent fast forwarding:

```
 var vid = $("#divVideo");
    var suptime = 0;
    vid.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
        if (!vid.seeking){
            suptime = vid.currentTime;
        }
    });
    vid.addEventListener('seeking', function(){
        var delta = vid.currentTime - suptime;
        if (Math.abs(delta) > 0.01) {
            vid.currentTime = suptime;
        }
    });
```

In my _Layout page I have:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
```

So I am using everything I have found searching but it still gives me the error.  I am using jQuery 3.1.1.

Comment: Use `on()` of **jQuery** or `document.getElementById('divVideo).addEventListener`.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Jquery is not JavaScript, but a set of tools built in JavaScript. You cannot use native JavaScript API's with jquery objects (Without selecting the raw nodes from it). Either use jQuery all the way, or native API's all the way. Mix and matching is a recipe for pain and tears.

Comment: @ste2425 actually it's pretty simple, see my answer and working snippet.

Comment: @zer00ne yes the access is simple, the maintainability and scalability of the mixing the API's not so, especially for new developers leading to issues like this. However that is our opinion where i work and why it was a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) if you are using jQuery,

And to get `seeking` and `currentTime` you need to use `[0]` to access these properties (So Javascript Version is better, when you want to access the element properties directly.)

```
var vid = $("#divVideo");
var suptime = 0;
vid.on('timeupdate', function(){
    if (!vid[0].seeking){ // to get seeking use [0], when using jquery object
        suptime = vid[0].currentTime;
    }
}).on('seeking', function(){ // chaining is better to use here
    var delta = vid[0].currentTime - suptime;
    if (Math.abs(delta) > 0.01) {
        vid[0].currentTime = suptime;
    }
});
```

Without jQuery, if you want to use `addEventListener` then try to use `getElementById()` like,

```
var vid = document.getElementById("divVideo");
var suptime = 0;
vid.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
    if (!vid.seeking){ // directly seeking and currentTime are accessible
        suptime = vid.currentTime;
    }
});
vid.addEventListener('seeking', function(){
    var delta = vid.currentTime - suptime;
    if (Math.abs(delta) > 0.01) {
        vid.currentTime = suptime;
    }
});
```